# Deploy App with Graph to SC App catalog

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an app which should be only available to one Site Collection, so I created an SC App catalog and deployed it there. But now I won't get an connection to Microsoft Graph and if I look at API Access, there is no request for the App.

Is is possible to get access to Microsoft Graph from an app which is only deployed on an Site Collection?
Maybe I can deploy it tenant wide, approve the access and delete the app afterwards and then deploy it on the SC App catalog. Is this the way to go or is there maybe a manifest configuration?

Thanks and bests

Martin

Comment: Is this an SPFx app?

Answer (score 0):

The tenant-deployed workaround might work but there is an easier way.
You can add the permission requests via PowerShell or the O365 CLI.

https://www.voitanos.io/blog/consider-avoiding-declarative-permissions-with-azure-ad-services-in-sharepoint-framework-projects/